# Open a small window while in Vim for executing commands

Tags: shell, vim

I need to write lot of code and compile very often. I hate switching back and forth various windows just to compile the code. Is it possible to open a small window at bottom and run invoke shell and close that window when needed?

Comment: Maybe map a single key to shell out and compile and then Ctrl-D to return... http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Mapping_keys_in_Vim_-_Tutorial_(Part_1)

Comment: but sometimes we may have to run multiple commands

Answer (score 1):

With GVim or MacVim, you can run external commands in the command-line: Gvim/MacVim comes with a (very) limited shell that will happily show you whatever the compiler outputs. The general usage pattern is:

```
:!command
:!command %
```

With CLI Vim, the same method will pause Vim and return to the shell to execute your command.

In both cases, you'll get a message asking you to press ENTER to come back to your normal editing.

Using `:make | cw` would be a slightly more sophisticated alternative, with the added bonus of showing the errors in the quickfix window.

An even more sophisticated approach would be to use Tim Pope's [Dispatch](https://github.com/tpope/vim-dispatch) plugin in combination with tmux or screen.

Comment: I recommend using `:make`.  See `:help quickfix` and try to avoid arguments about whether vim is an IDE.

Comment: @benjifisher WHO said I am trying to have arguments whether Vim is an IDE? Mind your words in public forum. I too love Vim the only thing is that I want to use Vim more productively So I am asking questions.

Comment: @username_4567:  I did not mean to suggest that you would start a pointless argument.  I just wanted to warn you that it is all to easy to be drawn into one.  "Mind your words in public" is good advice! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a problem for Screen
http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/

Quick reference of commands
http://aperiodic.net/screen/quick_reference

Comment: but how to create a small window at bottom?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe map a key to shell out to the compiler and run the program if compilation is successful:

```
:map F8 :!cc % && ./a.out
```

---

Or maybe just

```
:sh
make run
Ctrl-D
```

---

Another option is to suspend `vi`, using <kbd>Ctrl-Z</kbd> and do your stuff in the shell, then type `fg` to bring `vim` back to the foreground. Note that this is actually a feature of your shell, rather than `vim` but it produces the effect you seek.

Note this idea originates from the book *"Efficient Linux at the Command Line"* by Daniel Barrett. I forget the page number.

Answer (score 0):

I use `tmux` to achieve something like that. I have the following in my *~/.tmux.conf* file:

```
bind s splitw -v -p 25 -c '#{pane_current_path}' '/bin/bash'
bind q kill-pane
```

On pressing *Ctrl-b + s* (*prefix + s*), a new pane containing a bash shell opens up at the bottom. I can run shell commands from there: *find*, *grep*, *make*, etc. When I'm done, I press *Ctrl-b + q* to close the shell.

To enable `tmux` on every bash session, add the following to your *~/.bashrc*:

```
[[ -z "$TMUX" ]] && exec tmux
```